# Channel displaying on more than one page

Tags: channel, entry

I've recently inherited a EE site.  I'm a Joomla kid but that doesn't matter.  The owner of this website has multiple channels (I guess that's what they're called, such as Residential, Commercial, etc).  The channels (residential and commercial) are all showing up on one page, which is what they want.  However, the "In Progress" channel is showing up on more than one page.  I figured there has to be a simple setting to tell the channel how many entries on one page, sort of like Joomla, but can't seem to find it.

the site, if you want is www.newenglanddesign (.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on my mobile so I can't be verbose, but I'd bet you have a channel entries tag living on your templates. They look like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10"}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You can set what channels get outputted with that channel param, and can put multiple channel names pipe separated.

```
channel="news|weather"
```

Check out the docs:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html